# Why am I getting an extra character in my do while loop?

Tags: c++, do-while

In my code below I am trying to write a character in a file until user types '$'. When I compile it, it should print

```
Enter $ to exit.
: l
: k
: $
```

But in contrary it prints

```
Enter $ to exit.
: l
: : k
: : $
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch;
  ofstream out("Test2.txt");
  if(!out)
  {
    cout<<"Hello!! Sorry."<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Enter $ to exit."<<endl;
  do
  {
    cout<<": ";
    cin.get(ch);
    out.put(ch);
  } while(ch!='$');
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Hint: When you entered `'l'`, did you type one or 2 keys?

Comment: I put an enter after each character

Comment: BTW, if the file `Test2.txt` fails to open, your program continues anyway.  You may want to remove the test, return a 1 or place the remaining code in an `else` clause.

Comment: So code is printing `ch` once for `'l'` and the next loop for `enter`.

Comment: You may want to use `cin >> ch` instead of `cin.get()`.  The latter will ignore whitespace.

Comment: When you press Enter, that generates `ch='\r'`

Comment: oh now i get it, thanks a lot

Comment: @MarkLakata - the enter key produces `'\n'`, not `'\r'`. That newline character may be encoded as 0x0A on some systems, but that's the external representation, not the C++ escape code for that character.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker - yes, you are correct. However, depending on some systems and terminal emulator "workarounds" sometimes, `\n` and `\r` get swapped around (as they clearly get swapped around in my brain). And if you type Enter while entering a text file on  DOS/Windows machine, you get both "\r\n"

Comment: @MarkLakata - no, you're missing my point. In source code, `'\n`' is a newline character. If you read individual characters from any text source (console or file), `if (ch == '\n')` is the way to test for the end of a line. On **all** systems. The representation of that line ending in a text file may be something completely different (especially on file systems that don't have any notion of lines), but the standard library is responsible for understanding how line endings are represented and presenting them to the program as the single character `'\n'`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - If you import a Windows CRLF text file into Linux, you will get \r + \n. Luckily the '\n' comes after the '\r', so looking for '\n' as the end of line character will work, but your Linux code will see the '\r' character come before the '\n'.  Old Macs used '\r' as the EOL character, which made things worse... nothing is ever as simple as it should be, and I spend most of my working day dealing with gotchas like this. Not as bad as the evil utf-8 BOM character though...

Comment: @MarkLakata - if you read a text file that was created on a different system you may well find that your program does not correctly handle the foreign system's line ending conventions. Regardless, you have no guarantee that `'\n'` in source code corresponds to any particular byte value in a text file, whether it was created on your own system or it comes from some other system. Text files are not portable across systems without modifying the line endings. That's why programs like FTP have text mode: they figure out the difference between the systems and modify the file appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing one get function and hits one get function in compiling. You can avoid it by adding one more cin at the end of your do block.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch;
  ofstream out("Test2.txt");
  if(!out)
  {
    cout<<"Hello!! Sorry."<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Enter $ to exit."<<endl;
  do
  {
    cout<<": ";
    ch=0;
    cin.get(ch);
    out.put(ch);
    cin.get(ch);
  } while(ch!='$');
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Or by using `>>` operator:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch;
  ofstream out("Test2.txt");
  if(!out)
  {
    cout<<"Hello!! Sorry."<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"Enter $ to exit."<<endl;
  do
  {
    cout<<": ";
    ch=0;
    cin>>ch;
    out.put(ch);
  } while(ch!='$');
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the `od` (octal dump Linux utility) after your program runs. You'll see it is 5 characters long, thus explaining why there are 5 colons printed.

```
$ od -t x1 -t a Test2.txt
0000000  6c  0a  6b  0a  24
          l  nl   k  nl   $
0000005
```

Answer (score 0):

Try c cuz it's better for this problem

Answer (score -2):

For some reason your do while loop is running a 2nd time ..how about try not using a do while loop and an if statement instead just if != ch then execute